# MongoDb aggregates group Arrays object

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a mongo documentS like :

```
        {
         "id_" : ...,
         "company" "AAA":,
         "userId" : 80081624,
          "features" : [
            {
              "id" : 1,
              "nombre" : "size",
              "normal" : 1, (1 or 0)
              "alt" : 0, (1 or 0)
            },
            ...
            ,{
              "id" : 8,
              "nombre" : "name",
              "normal" : 0, (1 or 0)
              "alt" : 1, (1 or 0)
            }
          ]
        },
        {
         "id_" : ...,
         "company" "BBB":,
         "userId" : 8008555,
          "features" : [
            {
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : "yyyy",
              "normal" : 0, (1 or 0)
              "alt" : 1, (1 or 0)
            },
            {...},{...}
          ]
        }
```

And I would like to be able to group them by company and get the percentage of "normal" or "alt" for them. For now my code is like this:

```
collection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.unwind("$inductores"),

                        Aggregates.group("$features.id",
                                Accumulators.avg("n","$features.normal"),
                                Accumulators.avg("alt","$features.alt")),
                        Aggregates.sort(ascending("_id")),
                        Aggregates.project(new org.bson.Document("id","$features.id")
                                .append("n","$n")
                                .append("alt","$alt"))
                )

        ).forEach(printBlock);
```

And this show me by shell:

```
{"_id": 1, "n": 1.0, "alt": 0.0}
{"_id": 8, "n": 0.7, "alt": 0.0}
{....}
```

But i would like show me this:

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5e45056845b5da211aa04ec4"),
      "company" : "BBB",
      "features" : [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "yyy",
          "normal" : “20%”,
          "alt" : “45%”
        },
        {...}
        ,{
          "id" : 3,
          "nombre" : "XXX",
          "normal" : “10%”,
          "alt" : “20%”
        }
      ]
    },
    {...}
```

I have tried several ways to group the companies first but have not been able to get results.

---

edit: 
I have got the command in mongo language, I would only have to translate it to java but it is impossible for me.
I am using driver version 3.12

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$feature"},          

      {
         $group: { "_id": {"company" :"$company", "name":"$feature.name", "Id":"$feature.id"},
            "n" : {"$sum":"$feature.normal"},  
            "a1" : {"$sum":"$feature.alterado1"},
         }
      },  

       {$sort: {"_id.Id": 1}},

      {        
    $project: {
       "name":"$feature.name",
       "normal": $concat: [{ $toString: { "$round": [ { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": [100,{"$sum":["$n","$a"]}]}, "$n"]},2] }}," %"],
       "alt": $concat: [{ $toString: { "$round": [ { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": [100,{"$sum":["$n","$a"]}]}, "$a"]},2] }}," %"],
        }

      },

      { $group : {
          _id :  "$_id.company",
          feature: {
              $push: {
                    id:"$_id.Id",
                    name:"$_id.name",
                    Normal:"$normal",
                    Alterate: "$alt"
              }
          }
       }
     },

    ],{ allowDiskUse: true }  

    ).pretty();
```

Comment: I think you may need to `$group`, with `$push` to rebuild the array

Comment: Okay i go to try this, thanks

Comment: Can you show me some example? I don't really know how I can do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Java driver. I can suggest how to do this in the mongo shell and leave it to you to translate into Java.

Assuming that the collection will contain more than one document for each company, and each company document can have the same features with different options, the pipeline will need to

- unwind the features array so each document has a company with 1 feature
- group the documents by company-feature and count the total number of occurrences as well as normal/alt.  Since the schema calls for alt and normal to be 1 or 0, you can just sum these instead of using $cond as you would need if they were boolean.
  **Note:** If it can be safely assumed that a feature is either normal or alt, and never both or neither, then you would only need to count one and can calculate the percentage of `alt` as `1 - (percentage of normal)`, which might be a bit faster.
- calculate the percentages from the counted values
- re-group by company and push the features into an array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$features"},
    {$group: {
         _id:{company:"$company",feature:"$features.id"},
         name:{$first:"$name"},
         nombre:{$first:"$nombre"},
         count:{$sum:1},
         normal:{$sum:"$normal"},
         alt:{$sum:"$alt"}
    }},
    {$project:{
         normal:{$round:[{$mulitply:[100,{$divide:["$normal","$count"]}]},0]},
         alt:{$round:[{$mulitply:[100,{$divide:["$alt","$count"]}]},0]}
    }},
    {$group:{_id:"$company", features:{$push:"$features"}}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Let me try to translate it into java and do some tests and I'll tell you, but it looks good.